# Magento 2: Multi website session issue

Tags: magento2, session, header, multi-website

I am a beginner to magento and I have created a magento 2 multi-website and the URL looks like `http://127.0.0.1/testproject/` and `http://127.0.0.1/testproject/test`.

On these websites, while I have logged into `http://127.0.0.1/testproject/` site, It will show the currently logged in username and compare products in the header link that's fine.

But in another tab I have logged into `http://127.0.0.1/testproject/test` site, It also keeps the first site logged-in username and compare products data.

Similarly if logged into `http://127.0.0.1/testproject/test` first means, this login username and compare products will be shown on another website(http://127.0.0.1/testproject/) also.

And I have set 'No' to share the customer between websites in configuration.
If I was removed the browser cache and session means, It will be showing correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have different domains URL for cookie storage related to session.

Such as

- `http://127.0.0.1/testproject1/`
- `http://127.0.0.1/testproject2/`

OR

- `http://firstdomain.test/testproject/`
- `http://seconddomain.test/testproject/`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But in magento 2 we have the option to create multiple websites within the same domain. right?

Comment: I do not think  so, but I may be wrong.